# Add to an array of objects, a value into an attribute in an object

Tags: javascript

I'm new to the site, I have a problem with javascript that I'm not sure how to fix.

I have 2 arrays:
In the first array I have elements of the form index_rating, i.e. the first number indicates the index in the second array, where I want to update the rating.

I want to solve this, but do not know how

```js
let index_rating_array = ["0_1", "2_3", "3_5", "1_0"];

let preferArray = [
{prefer: "sport_swimming", rating: ""},
{prefer: "sport_tennis", rating: ""},
{prefer: "sport_running", rating: ""},
{prefer: "study_archeology", rating: ""}];

let updatedArray = [];
index_rating_array.forEach(element => {

console.log(preferArray[parseInt(element.split('_')[0])]);
console.log(Object.keys(parseInt(element.split('_')[0])));
updatedArray.push(preferArray[parseInt(element.split('_')[0])].rating = element.split('_')[1]);

});

console.log(updatedArray);
```

I want to get it:

```
[
{prefer: "sport_swimming", rating: "1"},
{prefer: "sport_tennis", rating: "0"},
{prefer: "sport_running", rating: "3"},
{prefer: "study_archeology", rating: "5"}]
```

Comment: Sort `index_rating_array` by the "index" part of the string, and then join the two arrays by using map?

Answer (score 0):

After splitting the parts of `element`, use the first part as the index into `preferArray`. Then update the `rating` property of that element.

```js
let index_rating_array = ["0_1", "2_3", "3_5", "1_0"];

let preferArray = [
  {prefer: "sport_swimming", rating: ""},
  {prefer: "sport_tennis", rating: ""},
  {prefer: "sport_running", rating: ""},
  {prefer: "study_archeology", rating: ""}
];

index_rating_array.forEach(element => {
  let [index, rating] = element.split("_");
  preferArray[index].rating = rating;
});

console.log(preferArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider sort `index_rating_array` by the "index" part of the string, and then join the two arrays by using map.

```js
let index_rating_array = ["0_1", "2_3", "3_5", "1_0"];

let preferArray = [{
    prefer: "sport_swimming",
    rating: ""
  },
  {
    prefer: "sport_tennis",
    rating: ""
  },
  {
    prefer: "sport_running",
    rating: ""
  },
  {
    prefer: "study_archeology",
    rating: ""
  }
];

index_rating_array.sort();

let outputArray = preferArray.map((el, idx) => ({
  ...el,
  rating: index_rating_array[idx].slice(-1)
}));

console.log(outputArray)
```

This does rely on `index_rating_array` and `preferArray` having the same number of items, and no items are missing or duplicated.